# Kotlinx.Serialization deserializing dates

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, kotlinx

I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to deserialize date fields.
How do i achieve this? Most solutions i found on SO don't work or they use classes that are no longer available

```
@Serializable
data class Dashboard(
    val someNumber: Int,
    val someDate: Date? // Custom Deserialization from unix timestamp
)
```

**EDIT:** Most solution i found use `PrimitiveSerialDescriptor` which seems to be not available

Comment: I believe you should write a customer serializer ([example](https://proandroiddev.com/custom-kotlinx-serializers-cd148e72d712)).

Comment: @azizbekian it uses `Unresolved reference: PrimitiveSerialDescriptor` which doesn't resolve

Comment: Did you add the corresponding import `import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveSerialDescriptor`?

Comment: "Custom Deserialization from unix timestamp" In that case just declare it as a `Long`. Conversions is not what a @Serializable is for.

Comment: seems like PrimitiveSerialDescriptor is available only after 1.0.0+ library version

Answer (score 15):

Do not use Date, but use **Instant** or **LocalDateTime** instead, you need to add this in build.gradle file

```kotlin
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.3.2"
```

read more about it in this link:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime

This will automatically Serializable and also work in KMM

Comment: This isn't working when trying to serialize .NET DateTime

Comment: @tom-williamI can't exactly help the API is written in C#, we don't get to choose what the API is written in

Comment: @Eman I know, then you should not ask here, you should make new articles and ask about C# serialization because this is only about Kotlin serialization. 

Comment: seeing as my android app is written in kotlin, I thought it was fitting, but I figured it out anyway :P

Comment: After adding that library I'm still getting the message "Serializer has not been found for type 'LocalDateTime'". Is there any additional setup needed?
Edit: found the issue, it needs to be kotlinx.datetime.LocalDateTime

Answer (score 10):

There is good documentation for the latest version of **kotlinx.serialization** https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers

However, there is no `PrimitiveSerialDescriptor` class in the question which means, that some older version of **kotlinx.serialization** is used.

From https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/releases it could be found out that in version **1.0.0-RC**

> `PrimitiveDescriptor` was renamed to `PrimitiveSerialDescriptor`

and

> The id of the core artifact with `@Serializable` annotation and `Json` format was changed from `kotlinx-serialization-runtime` to `kotlinx-serialization-core` to be more clear and aligned with other kotlinx libraries.

Following that, here is an example of code for **kotlinx.serialization** version **0.20.0**:

```
object DateSerializer : KSerializer<Date> {
    override val descriptor = PrimitiveDescriptor("Date", PrimitiveKind.LONG)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Date) = encoder.encodeLong(value.time)
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Date = Date(decoder.decodeLong())
}

@Serializable
data class MyDto(
    @Serializable(DateSerializer::class)
    val date: Date
)

fun main() {
    val dto = Json.parse(MyDto.serializer(), """{ "date" : 1630407000000 }""")
    println(dto.date)
}
```

with `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.72"
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-serialization-runtime", "0.20.0")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To deserialize

```
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializer
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale


@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
@Serializer(forClass = Date::class)
object DateSerializer {
    private val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Date {
        val dateString = decoder.decodeString()
        return format.parse(dateString)
    }

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Date) {
        val dateString = format.format(value)
        encoder.encodeString(dateString)
    }
}
```

then in your `@Serializable` class,

```
@Serializable(with = DateSerializer::class)
val date: Date,
```

the dependencies at app level `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0'
```

you may need to play around with the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` as this answer deals with `2023-June-05` format.